# Mongoose optional search query parameters?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a following situation.
I need to build a mongoose query, based on certain arguments if present.

I.e. if object like this is passed

```
{
    player: "nickname",
    action: "capture"
}
```

the following search is performed:

```
Entry.find({
    player: obj.player,
    action: obj.action
}).
    exec(function(err, res){
        console.log(res);
    });
```

If I need to exclude "action" from search if action is not in the object, what should I do?
Using ternary operator like `action: (obj.action) ? obj.action:null` doesn't work, as would search entries in DB where `action` is `null`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Build up your query object programmatically:

```
var query = {
    player: 'player'
};

if (obj.action) {
    query.action = obj.action;
}

Entry.find(query).exec(function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Wow, didn't even think of that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the order of fields in the query so created and the Entry model matter?

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks.. and do you know if I want to search values greater than a particular range in this query-say there is a field called "budget" and we need to find all budgets greater than the given value?

Answer (score 9):

With ES6, you can do this with a splat & ternary like this:

```
Entry.find({
  player: obj.player,
  ...obj.action ? { action: obj.action } : {}
})
.exec(function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: I favor this as it is a 1 liner

Answer (score 5):

In case someone encounters same question, here's how I solved it:

```
var query = {
    player: 'player'
};

Entry.find({
    player: query.player,
    action: (query.action) ? query.action:/.*/
}).
    exec(function(err, res){
        console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: A downside to this approach is that using the regex will hurt query performance. It's better to just omit the field from the query.

Comment: @JohnnyHK that's correct. 4 years on with ES6, you can avoid the regex with [a splat & ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339775/441930)