# MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline Dynamic Match Queries

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to use the match pipeline stage to dynamically filter based on given parameters that may or may not be undefined when I call the function.

For example, if I passed in a JSON object to the function that contains a value for Field1, I would have a match pipeline like the following:

```
        {
        "$match": {
            "Field1": Field1_value
        }}
```

However, if I had a JSON object passed into the function that contains values for Field1 and Field 2, I would like to have a match pipeline like the following:

```
        {
        "$match": {
            "Field1": Field1_value,
            "Field2": Field2_value
        }}
```

Is there a simple way to do this that wouldn't involve having to write static pipelines for each combination of fields that I pass to this function?

Comment: Just build up your query programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995166/mongoose-optional-search-query-parameters

Comment: @JohnnyHK thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your are not programming in pure Mongo. If so, you could use whatever else you are using to prepare the `$match` object.

here is an Example on Javascript

```
var pipeline = function(parameters){
    return [
        {
        $match:parameters,
        }
        // put here other stages
    ]
};

// first call
collection.aggregate(
    pipeline({"Field1": Field1_value}), options, callback
);
// second call
collection.aggregate(
    pipeline({"Field1": Field1_value, "Field2": Field2_value}), options, callback
)
```

If the `$match` operation is not the first of your pipeline and depends of a previous operation, I think it is not possible to do it.