# Mongoose find and check if all queries are given

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with my app. 
Im trying to set filters working, so im using mongoose find method.

I have something like that:

```
 Campsite
    .find({
            name: req.query.name,
            country: req.query.country
        })
```

How i can force my query to check if user gave all the data?
For example i want user to search only by name and get results, search only by country and get results and search by both queries and also get result by combining both of values

Right now the code above works like that:
When user types name and leaves empty country it wont find anything because it kinda sends an empty country even if its disabled as an input and when i remove country property from my query and user search for the name he gets correct results.

How i can fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose optional search query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995166/mongoose-optional-search-query-parameters)

Comment: yes. Thats what i was looking for but is there a way to include the $lt parameter?

Comment: Yes, certainly. Something like pseudocode: `if(userdata.maxvalue) { query.somefield: { $lt: userdata.maxvalue}}`

Comment: Already tried doing something like this, but it gives me an error of unexpected token :

Comment: Show us the code that you have and we might be able to help.